# Prove that the set of Real numbers R can be partitioned into a denumerable collection of uncountable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Prove** that the set of Real numbers **R** can be *partitioned* into a *denumerable* collection of *uncountable sets*

My thoughts on the problem were to show the break down of the set of real numbers into *subsets* such as **rational, irrational, and integers.**

Im not sure if im over complicating this. The wording is confusing to me because i have never done something like this in class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the union of the intervals $[n, n+1); n $
in $\mathbb Z^+ $ ? and $(n-1,n]$ for $n$ in the negative integers less than or equal
to $-1$, and $(-1,0)$.

Basically, the partition is : { $ \cup (n-1,n ]; n \leq -1 \cup (-1,0) \cup [0,1) \cup [1,2) \cup....\cup [n, n+1) \cup.....$}

Comment: is it possible that the question actually asked for a partition into an uncountable number of countable sets? that is anyway a more challenging question, whose solution requires the use of the axiom of choice (cf Hamel basis)

Comment: I'm not sure , but there is another recent question asking precisely that.

Comment: @DavidHolden That might be slightly more challenging, but it still doesn't require the axiom of choice.  Consider $\{r + \mathbb{Z} : r \in [0,1)\}$.  Even partitioning $\mathbb{R}$ into $|\mathbb{R}|$ many sets of size $|\mathbb{R}|$ doesn't require the axiom of choice, although the generalization to arbitrary infinite cardinals in place of $\mathbb{R}$ does require it.

Comment: The question I asked is correct as states, but ur proposed question is interesting.  However I have an issue with ur answer to my problem. Wouldnt that set only cover integers? What about the rest of the real set?

Comment: @e2DAeyePi: Are you asking about my answer?

Comment: @user99680 I just went over this problem with two doctors at my local college. I misread ur answer, and you are correct. Thank you for your help

Comment: @e2daeyePi: No problem, glad to help.